# Extract lines from a text file using batch or vbs

Tags: file, batch-file, text, vbscript, dos

I have a text file and I'm trying to extract lines from it that begins with "422" (there are multiple per file) and paste all of those into a new text file. I'm not quite sure if it'd be better to do this in vbs or a batch file but either would work. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Apologies for seeming like a "do my work for me" question; my code was really short and not very effective but I'll post what I have so far:

cd "~%dp1"
findstr /B "422   " testfile.txt >> output.txt

The problem is that the code isn't taking the spaces after 422 into account so I'm getting extra values in my output.

Comment: You say you're "trying" - what exactly have you tried? As it stands this question is just a work request.

Comment: Updated with what I have so far,  apologies again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FINDSTR /B 422 "fileToSearch" >>"FileToCopyTo"
```

without the quotes, eg.

```
FINDSTR /B 422 C:\Users\John\Documents\filename.txt >>C:\Users\John\Documents\output.txt
```

Comment: You added spaces to the front of the commands? Not sure why you'd do that...?

Comment: four spaces at the beginning of the line marks the line as "code", so that it gets properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

As your question smells like "I need a job done" and not like "I want to learn (anything at all)" use a suitable tool, e.g. [findstr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Findstr):

```
type 31392125.txt
a
422b
c
d
e 422
422f
422 g

findstr /B 422 31392125.txt
422b
422f
422 g
```

Read the docs ():

> Use spaces to separate multiple search strings unless the argument is
>   prefixed with /C.  For example, 'FINDSTR "hello there" x.y' searches
>   for "hello" or "there" in file x.y.  'FINDSTR /C:"hello there" x.y'
>   searches for "hello there" in file x.y.

So:

```
findstr /B /C:"422 " 31392125.txt
422 g
```